# Exclude files while generating war in jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I am using `maven clean install` inside jenkins.

My war file contains a folder named ".ebextensions".

I written three different jobs in jenkins.

One is for production and one is for testing and one is for development.

I want to exclude some files inside '.ebextensions' directory while generating war in testing environment and exclude whole directory while generating war for development environment.

How to achieve this?

Comment: How do you build your war? Ant/maven/script? Can you show part of the script which copy classes?

Comment: I am using maven,clean install

Comment: So then this is not a [tag:jenkins] question..

Comment: in jenkins job ,I am passing clean and install

Comment: What kind of things are in this folder which is different based on the environment? Sounds like properties? See https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Add exclude to maven-jar-plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/ebextensions/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

if you need for specific environment and maven doesn't support if statements,
you could use Ant-contrib's if task

```
<configuration>
          <tasks>
            <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"
              classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
            <if>
              <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="development" />
              <then>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/ebextensions/*</exclude>
          </excludes>

              </then>
              <else>
                <echo message="Do not exclude" />
              </else>
            </if>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
```

and send to maven env parameter as: `mvn install -Denv=development`

Comment: But it have to be their in production environment and testing environment.Is it possible to exclude based on environment specific

Comment: folder name contains .(dot) infront of ebextensions.So it is not showing in eclipse but it exists in workspace.If i exclude .ebextensions in maven jar plugin it is not excluding.If i exclude assets folder it is working fine. (.ebextensions is infrastructure related folder which is related to aws elastic beanstalk.I am trying to deploy it in aws.)